# How can I receive the data by NSURLConnection in other thread in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

I write iPhone application. In this app, I use Twitter framework. In this framework, call back function made in desynchronization is in other thread.

In my view controller,

ViewController.m

```
 [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType
                        withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                            if (granted) {
                                if (account == nil) {
                                    NSArray *accountArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
                                    account = [accountArray objectAtIndex:2];
                                }

                                if (account != nil){
                                    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json"];
                                    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                                    [params setObject:@"1" forKey:@"count"];

                                    TWRequest *request = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                         parameters:params 
                                      requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];
                                    [request setAccount:account];
                                    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                                        if (responseData) {
                                            //Throw response data to other Web API
                                            [self otherAPI:responseData];
                                            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
                                        }
                                    }];

                                }
                            }


                        }];
```

And I write these method in this class.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
```

But I cannot receive full data from other API. I can receive only first data. I think there are some problems in conducting multi thread. 
Therefore I'd like to let me know what's wrong in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see your problem. `-connection:didReceiveData:` is called multiple times, you need build up a NSMutableData object which will contain the whole message.

Note: This only works for a single download per instance at one time.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    self.responseData = [[NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // self.responseData has all the data.
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. But I have already done that option. After that, I solved this problem. I use Japanese. So -(NSString*)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding  method looks like needed. I can receive whole data. I think that NSLog cannot show non escaped data. Thank you.